# How to use django-trix in a Django Project?

Tags: django, python-3.x, rich-text-editor

I have added trix in my **model.py**

```
from trix.fields import TrixField
.....
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = TrixField('content')
    time_added = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Article Name: {}, Added: {}'.format(self.title, self.time_added)
.....
```

It shows results like **this photo bellow** in my Django-admin which I loved:
[image]

but it doesn't shows my desired output in my **Template**
[image]
The View.py

```
class FeaturedArticle(ListView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'featuredarticles'
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Article.objects.filter(time_added__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-time_added')[:5]
```

The Template part

```
<!-- article area  -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="blog-post-title">Featured Articles</h2>
                <!-- tempalate tag here -->
                    {% for article in featuredarticles %}
                        <hr>
                        <h3>{{article.title}}</h3>
                        <p>{{article.content}}</p>
                <!-- tempalate tag here -->
                    {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br>
<!-- article area end -->
```

How can I **fix** it

Comment: Show us how you are rendering this in the template?

Comment: That is what I need to know. How can i render it? perfectly

Comment: What I'm asking is for you to show us how you're rendering it "imperfectly", so that we can show you where the error is.

Comment: edited the question with your desired need.......please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`article.content` contains HTML, which Django will escape by default. You can use the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter to ensure the content is not escaped:

```
{{ article.content|safe }}
```

This does of course mean that arbitrary HTML can be inserted into your page, so you should be careful about who has the ability to edit that field.

Answer (score 0):

`<p>{{article.content|safe}}</p>`

or
use mark_safe in views

from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

content = `"<h1>hi</h1>"`
return render(request, 'hi.html', {'content': content})